# Wrong Math.Pow() implementation for NaN number in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, math

Why the `Math.Pow(1.0, double.NaN)` command returns `NaN` instead of the correct `1.0`? I understand `NaN` as an indefinite value (mathematically) that represents all the real numbers including positive and negative infinities.
And for all these values, the expression is always mathematically correct and equals 1.0.

E.g. Python has it, and  `1**float("nan") == 1` is `True`, in accordance with [IEEE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pow.html) standard:

> For any value of y (including NaN), if x is +1, 1.0 shall be returned.

Comment: I've included several links to bits of Microsoft documentation. So far as I can see, nothing in the `Math` (or `Math.Pow`) documentation claims that it's an implementation of the IEEE `pow` function, so the documentation for that is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: It depends on what version of .NET you use.  The desktop version has [explicit code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/08786f20e89eb5f518d8d25f3e7f886f69d994ea/src/classlibnative/float/floatdouble.cpp#L174) to check for the NaN corner case, returning NaN as documented in the MSDN article.   This check however [was removed](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/10295) in .NETCore, incorrectly as far as I can tell.  But certainly with the underlying desire to make it behave like the CRT pow() function does.  Everybody hates a failing unit test.

Comment: `Math.Sqrt(-1)` does not appear to give me NaN in python, NaN could be defined differently in different languages. Square root of -1 gives NaN in C# and throws an error in python so how can you compare these two implementations of NaN?

Comment: I agree with you, Python's NaN vs. .NET NaN are different, but python is still consistent with IEEE standard for `sqrt()`: `These functions shall fail if: The finite value of x is < -0,  or x is -Inf.`. I take it that .NET does not respect IEEE and it is sad for me.

Answer (score 4):

Any operation using a NaN returns NaN therefore `Math.Pow(1.0, double.Nan)` will return NaN. This is expected behaviour when using NaN in C#.

> a method call with a NaN value or an operation on a NaN value returns
>   NaN

[See Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.nan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2/)

Just because one language behaves in a certain way doesn't necessarily mean another language will behave that way

EDIT: for future reference `Math.Pow(1.0, double.PositiveInfinity)` does give you one and I think this is what you are looking for. Check out the documentation on the language for how the NaN is used. If you want to use the postive and negative infinities then use the `double.PostiveInfinitity` or the `double.NegativeInfinity` as NaN does not represent these values.

Comment: But is inccoret with [IEEE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pow.html): "For any value of y (including NaN), if x is +1, 1.0 shall be returned."

Comment: "The act of reaching an invalid result is called a floating-point exception. An exceptional result is represented by a special code called a NaN" - so any operation with a NaN results in a NaN because it will give you a floating point exception and a number which cannot be expressed.

Answer (score 3):

There are specific representations for [Negative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.negativeinfinity?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Positive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.positiveinfinity?view=netframework-4.7.2) infinities, so whatever [`NaN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.nan?view=netframework-4.7.2) is, it doesn't represent those.

The example given in the documentation for an expression that can produce a `NaN` is `0.0/0.0`. Whatever the result of that is, it's *not* some "indefinite real number" as you asserted.

---

Rather than assuming that [`Math.Pow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) necessarily promises to follow the conventions of another language or standard (as you've linked to in your question), you should check its own documentation that specifically states its behaviour with respect to `NaN`s:

> ```
> Parameters        Return value
> x or y = NaN.     NaN
> ```

The above is the first line from a table in the remarks section. The below appears further down in the table:

> ```
> Parameters                        Return value
> x = 1; y is any value except NaN. 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

NaN stands for "Not a Number" so a NaN return seems right to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is desirable behavior. You might think `Math.Pow(1, double.NaN)` returning `1` as the reasonable choice, and you *could* make an argument in your favor when it concerns string literals, but IMHO opinion it goes down the drain when the following happens:

```
var i = Whatever();
var d = SomeRatherDifficultOperationYouDidntImplement();
var result = Math.Pow(i, d);
```

Why should this return `1`? Maybe `d` being `NaN` is something that shouldn't be happening; you are swallowing a potential bug here. `NaN` should propagate always, chances are that some previous computation went wrong somewhere.

If you have a specific scenario where `Math.Pow(1, double.NaN)` needs to be `1` then use specific code for that case and comment it so its clear that its specified and required behavior.

Comment: I rewrite the math code in python to c# (if it's a good language for mathematical algorithms is another question), where there are structures similar to this

```plane_factor = (x * y) ** 2 / (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
density = 1 / norm * math.cosh (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** plane_factor``` Where the author of original python code assumes (maybe implicitly) validity for all `x, y`. It's not problem check (x,y) on (0,0) in C# code, but I was surprised that is inconsitent. Naively, I think that c# implements the IEEE-1985 float number standard, with which the python code was probably calculated.

Comment: Why should it return 1? That has been answered in the deliberations of the IEEE committee that developed the standard. Now I don't know what the rationale was but I'm sure it was well thought out and reasoned.